# Flutter column shows extra space between widgets in Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Column widget is showing extra space between consecutive widgets even when using simple containers with their padding set to 0. I have tried using SizedBox, setting mainAxisSize to min but nothing seems to be working.
Moreover this issue is only appearing in **Android OS** and not on Web or iOS.

**My Code:**

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 150,
          color: Colors.black,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Output:
[image]

I have zoomed the image a bit to on the right to display the gap better. There is a line of space appearing between the 2 containers. I have placed another container of 150 height below the column to show the difference between complete opaque and space. I have recreated this same behaviour on Pixel 3 Emulator as well as OnePlus 6T device.

Can anybody help me with a fix to this. I know this can be solved using Stack and Positioned but I was hoping to find out if this is an issue in Flutter SDK or a fixable widget behaviour.

Comment: Feels like a bug to me to be honest, posted a possible work-around below.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty annoying effect indeed. And though I can't tell you *why* this is happening, playing around with it a bit, it seems that giving the Container a BoxDecoration with a Border instead of a color removes the artifacts:

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('title'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          height: 51,
          //color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          height: 100,
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          height: 150,
          //color: Colors.black,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me answer didn't work (probably because i had clipPath over container but i found similar solution)

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.yourColor),
    color:  Colors.yourColor,
),
```

In all containers at your column